# How can I get the bean definitions without actually creating the beans?

Tags: spring, static-analysis

For static analysis of my Spring config, I need just the bean definitions - actually creating the beans would cause problems because some need a (properly initialized) database.

Is there a way to prevent the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to create any beans? Instead, it should just load and analyze the config and stop.

Comment: making beans lazy instantiated would "prevent" initialization

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make all beans `@Lazy` :-( ... Or maybe I can if I could make `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` *think* that all beans were lazy :-/

Answer (score 1):

you could implement the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface. in the `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` method you have access to BeanDefinition's

```
public class MyBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        registry.getBeanDefinition("myBean");
    }
}
```

Comment: :-/ I guess, I could throw an expected exception after running my checks ... +1 for the idea but I hope there is a solution which doesn't need such a hack.

Comment: yeah, throwing a exception sounds dirty. and what about making you beans lazy instantiated? of course only works, if they are not used during initialization.

Comment: hm... alternative solutin would be to use `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader` outside of your ApplicationContext. for your static analysis voodoo you do not really need your ApplicationContext, do you? this step can be done before you initialize your application or even in a seperate process.